# Overlapping containers with use of rows?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I'm trying to mimic some of the look of this website:

http://quay.com.au/

Since I'm intrigued by the design. I'm wondering how to go about overlapping containers in rows using Bootstrap, since I've looked into the code and it seems like that's what they're using.

This is what I have for HTML so far:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-2"><div class="about img-rounded">
 <h3>About</h3>
 <p><b>Info1</b></p>
 <p>Info2 </p>
</div></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1"></div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-2"><div class="projects img-rounded">
 <h3>Projects</h3>
 <img class="img-responsive" src="img">
 <p>Description</p>
 <img class="img-responsive" src="img"> 
 <p>Description</p>
 <img class="img-responsive" src="img">
 <p>Description</p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3"><div class="work img-rounded">
 <h3>Work</h3>
</div></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Any suggestions? Something to do with z-index in css is my only guess...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code on the site the container has a position: relative and to get the sections overlapping the sections are offset from the top, like The Query Experience

```
.page-index .pattern-gray {
    top: -240px;
}
```

quick bootply http://www.bootply.com/Blms3j1GjO

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is called **Parallax Scrolling**.  There are several tutorials out there, and a full implementation would be difficult to include in one answer here.

**[Here's a good resource from David Walsh on this](http://davidwalsh.name/parallax)**

Basically, this is a combination of `background-attachment: fixed` and overlapping `div` elements, and some javascript to flop the selected image when it's hidden.

I hope that helps.

Comment: I actually have the parallax set up, I'm struggling to get the containers in Bootstrap to overlap. The 'Our Menus', photo, and 'The Quary Experience' bits here3 is what I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue in something like CodePen or jsFiddle?  Without it, any subsequent answer is going to be stabbing in the dark.